# How can I create a &mut MyEnum from &mut Nested?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have the following:

```rust
enum Item {
  None,
  Table(Table),
  ...
}

struct Table {
  ...
}
```

And let's say I have some table like this:

```rust
let t = &mut Table::new();
```

How would I go about upcasting `t` from a `&mut Table` into a `&mut Item`? If I try to convert directly like this:

```rust
let i = &mut Item::Table(t);
```

I get the error `mismatched types expected struct Table, found &mut Table`.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite problematic.

If you don't need the same address, then you can wrap it in `Item::Table`. The problem is that you need to have an owned `Table` but you only have it borrowed. You can take it from there, but you need to leave something in its place so the reference is still valid. You can use [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) to put [`Default::default()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html) inside or [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) to put something else. You can also use the [`replace_with`](https://docs.rs/replace_with) crate if you only need it temporarily.

```rust
let i = &mut Item::Table(std::mem::take(t));

let i = &mut Item::Table(std::mem::replace(t, Table::new()));

replace_with::replace_with_or_abort(t, |t| {
    let mut i = Item::Table(t);

    let i_ref = &mut i;
    // Work with `i_ref`...

    match i {
        Item::Table(t) => t,
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

If you do need it to have the same address, then you're out of luck. `Item` does not have the same layout as `Table`, and so you cannot do that.